# Method Not Allowed (POST): /

Tags: python, django, e-commerce

I'm trying to make a simple one-paged shop. I made a ListView of the items and it renders no problem. The shopping cart will be in a modal. I made the buy button, but whenever I press it, it says:

```
Method Not Allowed (POST): /
Method Not Allowed: /
[22/Dec/2021 11:40:04] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

Here are my views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Item
from .forms import AddCartForm

class ItemsListView(ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'main_page.html'

def aBuy(request):
    form = AddCartForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('BUY BUY')
    return render(request, 'main_page.html', {'form':form})
```

This is the form:

```
class AddCartForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['price', 'quantity']
```

The form in html:

```
<div class="col" style="text-align:left">
                          <form name="buy" method="POST">
                              {% csrf_token %}
                              {{ form }}
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info butt" value="Buy">
                          </form>
                      </div>
```

I cannot continue making the logic for adding it to the future cart because of it. `print('BUY BUY')` is just for testing.
In the url file it's only the main page with `ItemListView.as_view`. I tried putting the aBuy function in it and out, same problem remains.

Comment: Why do you expect Django to execute your `aBuy` view when you click the Buy button? You are trying to `POST` to your `ListView`, which is not supported (and is not what you want).

Comment: @Selcuk because it's in the `<form></form>`? How do I connect it?

Comment: Provide your urls.py please

Comment: `How do I connect it`: This is too broad to explain in a Stack Overflow comment. I suggest you to learn Django fundamentals from a tutorial first.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `action` attribute in your form:

```
<form action="/path-to-post-url/" method="post"> 
  {% csrf_token %} 
  {{ form }} 
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

You can read more about templatings and forms here  [Django Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/).